# Cross-referencing and markers between sections and text document

Tags: sectioning, cross-referencing

Assuming my sections have different names, a simple question: is there any way to use cross-references in the document to target to sections without using markers in the sections? It could be useful, for example, just to use something like this:

```
\ref{namesection}
```

Comment: Sounds like a question for the main site, not for meta. And yes, there are a few workarounds to do this, but it's a bad idea which will give you all kinds of problems, for example with special characters in section names etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution. It doesn't modify the definitions of `\section`, `\subsection`, and `\subsubsection`. This is useful because there should be no complications should the sectioning commands contain optional arguments that may show up in, say, the Table of Contents. Instead, the solution sets up a Lua function that scans the input lines at a very early stage of processing -- before LaTeX starts its usual proocessing -- and automatically replaces all instances of `\section{...}` with `\section{...}\label{...}`. The only input syntax requirement is that the `\section` commands and their associated full arguments all be on a single line -- no line breaks allowed.

All this said, I'd say it *must* be easier to simply provide a few `\label` statements by hand...

[image]

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
function add_label ( s )
  return ( string.gsub ( s , "(\\.-section.*)(%b{})", "%1%2\\label%2" ) )
end
\end{luacode}
\AtBeginDocument{\directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback(
   "process_input_buffer" , add_label , "add_label" )}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section[Hello]{Hello World} % note: no "\label" statement
\subsection[Goodbye]{Goodbye World} % note: no "\label" statement

A cross-reference to section \ref{Hello World}.

\noindent
Another cross-reference to subsection \ref{Goodbye World}.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can, with caution:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse,lipsum}

\let\oldsection\section
\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{s o m}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {% \section*
      \oldsection*{#3}% \section*[.]{..}
    }{% \section
      \IfValueTF{#2}
        {\oldsection[#2]{#3}}% \section[.]{..}
        {\oldsection{#3}}% \section{..}
    }%
    \label{#3}% Force label to match section title
}

\begin{document}

See Section~\ref{A section}.

\section{A section}

% This won't work
% \section{Another \textit{beautiful} section}

\end{document}
```

In order to set a `\label` that matches the section title, we rewrite `\section` (using [`xparse`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse), for ease-of-use).

Note that formatting (and other stuff) within sectional titles may cause problems.